# How to highlight preceeding space-indentation that isn't rounded to current width?

Tags: indentation, whitespace, highlighting

Is there a way to highlight (set the background color for example) the space before a line, when it's indentation isn't aligned to the current indentation-width?

4 spaces indentation for eg:

```
fn my_func() {
    if foo() {
        ##bar();
        blob();
    ###fez();
        baz();
    }
}
```

where the `#` characters represent the background showing a different color, back until the indentation is aligned to 4.

Of course this is only useful when code follows strict indentation conventions.

---

Note that I'm aware of emacs advanced auto-indentation features and indent-highlighting plugins, but would prefer something less intrusive that only shows up when there is an issue. A little like highlighting trailing spaces.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but functions like `c-indent-defun` will correct indentation for you, which might achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @Tyler, the issue is *you're* not always the only person writing the code. Checking out files written by others is quite a common use case - and you don't always want to re-indent their work either (bug-fixing or changes for code-review), so just seeing odd-indentation is useful.

Comment: That makes sense. Just checking - sometimes people ask how to get half-way to something, not realizing that Emacs will take you all the way to the goal. But your use-case is reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using font-lock...

```el
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '(("^ \\{4\\}*\\( \\{1,3\\}\\)[^ ]" 1 'match)))
```

Comment: Maybe nice to use `whitespace-trailing` instead of `match`

Comment: Modified to read the current tab width `(format "^ \\{%d\\}*\\( \\{1,%d\\}\\)[^ ]" tab-width (- tab-width 1))`
`

Comment: added a slightly expanded answer, feel free to copy from it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `font-lock-add-keywords`.

The example below shows you can can selectively enable this feature in your configuration - for different formats.

- Note the indentation is read from `tab-width`.
- This example uses `whitespace-trailing`, you may want to use `match` or any other color.

eg:

```el
;; highlight non-aligning indent offset
(defun highlight-indent-offset ()
 (font-lock-add-keywords
  nil
  `((,(lambda (limit)
        (re-search-forward
         (format "^ \\{%d\\}*\\( \\{1,%d\\}\\)[^ ]" tab-width (- tab-width 1))
         limit t))
     1 'whitespace-trailing))))
```

Then this function can be called for spesific modes: eg,

```el
(add-hook
 'rust-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (setq tab-width 4)
   (highlight-indent-offset)
   (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)))
```

---

*This is a minor changes to @politza's answer.*

Comment: Why not go all the way and make it a minor-mode.

Comment: I've never written a minor mode before, will need to look into it - what advantages would it have?

Comment: A minor-mode can be disabled.